# Proof of separating hyperplane theorem using minimax theorem for zero sum games

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, game-theory

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_M\in\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $P \equiv conv \{x_1,\ldots,x_M\}$ denote the convex hull of these points. Using the Minimax Theorem prove that for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^N \setminus P$ there exists a vector $v\in[-1,1]^N$ such that $v\cdot(x-y)>0$ for all $x\in{}P$.

(Hint: Find a way of identifying $v$ and $x$ with mixed
strategies in a zero-sum game.)

My attempt: I have been able to prove the other direction (that too with help from online lecture notes) - i.e. how to use the separating hyperplane theorem to prove the minmax theorem. But I'm unable to find a way to proceed with the direction required in the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well actually, I'm still trying to solve the problem using that hint, but have not been able to solve it. So if you want to make it more explicit that'll be really helpful. Thanks again though.

Comment: Would you pls consider saying more?

Comment: sure, which steps were you able to take using the hint?

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. Actually, between then and now, I was able to solve it (I think). I've posted my sol as an answer. Feel free to commentl on it.

Comment: I have given a similar proof that does not use any nomenclature from game theory.

Comment: @Canine360 Could you please provide the reference for the proof of the other direction (proving minimax theorem using hyperplane separation theorem)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $v^T(x-y)> 0$ for all $x \in P$ is the same as $\min_{x \in P} v^T(x-y) > 0$, and 'there exists a $v$' can turn this into "$\min_x \max_v$" or "$\max_v \min_x$" (one of the two, try to figure out which one). Then you can apply the minimax theorem and use that $x \neq y$.

---

> prove that for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^N \setminus P$ there exists a vector $v\in[-1,1]^N$ such that $v\cdot(x-y)>0$ for all $x\in{}P$.

For any $x \in P$ we have $\max_{v \in [-1,1]^N} v^T(x-y) = \sum_{i=1}^N |x-y|_i >0$ since $x\neq y$. Therefore $ \min_{x \in P} \max_{v \in [-1,1]^N} v^T(x-y) > 0$. By the minimax theorem:
$$\min_{x \in P} \max_{v \in [-1,1]^N} v^T(x-y) = \max_{v \in [-1,1]^N} \min_{x \in P} v^T(x-y)$$
so $\max_{v \in [-1,1]^N} \min_{x \in P} v^T(x-y)>0$, which means there exists a $v\in[-1,1]^N$ such that $\min_{x \in P} v^T(x-y)>0$, which means $v^T(x-y)>0$ for all $x \in P$.

Answer (score 1):

Using LinAlg's hint, here is my attempt:

Consider the two-player zero-sum game where player 1 (the maximizer) chooses $g\in\{-1,1\}^N$ and player 2 (the minimizer) chooses one of the points $j\in\{1,\ldots,M\}$, and player 1's payoff is $\sum_{k=1}^Ng_k\cdot(p^j_k-q_k)$. By the Minimax Theorem, this game has a value $v$. Note that we can identify mixed strategies of player 1 with elements of $[-1,1]^N$, and mixed strategies of player 2 can be identified with elements of $P$ (by taking expectations). So the expected utility of player 1 from a mixed strategy profile $(\gamma,p)$ is $\sum_{k=1}^N\gamma_k(p_k-q_k)$.

Let $\gamma^*\in[-1,1]^N$ be a maxminimizer and let $p^*\in P$ be a minmaximizer. Then $v=\sum_{k=1}^N\gamma^*_k\cdot(p^*_k-q_k)$. Note that $\gamma=p^*/\lVert p^*\rVert\in[-1,1]^N$, so $v\geq\sum_{k=1}^{N}\gamma_k\cdot(p^*_k-q_k)=\lVert p^*-q\rVert>0$ (since $q\notin P$, and hence $q\neq p^*$). Thus, the value is positive, and so for any mixed strategy $p$, we have $\sum_{k=1}^{N}\gamma^*_k(p_k-q_k)>0$, as desired.